# Increasing the upload size in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, upload, filesize

I wanted to increase the file upload size limit in wordpress without editing php.ini
So I tried adding .htaccess to the wp-content/uploads directory with rules like these:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

This doesn't work in wp-content/uploads, the upload max is still 2MB
This does work if I put this in the websites .htaccess file though.

Why won't this work if I just put the htaccess in the uploads directory?  Are there any risks in increasing the upload size for the entire site?

Comment: that htaccess file needs to run where the script is, which i believe is in wp-admin?

Comment: Depending on your web host, they may restrict this.

Comment: I do not know if the problem is in wordpress, but in my case my server only allows editing "php.ini" (root level) or phprc, .htaccess htaccess does not control the php on some servers.

Comment: An alternative is use PHP's `ini_set` function. If that doesn't work I'd guess your host is restricting it and to contact them.

Comment: @SetSailMedia I agree in part, but not necessarily a duplicate, it seems to be a variation of his server as I mentioned in my first comment (3# comment).

Comment: `.htaccess` won't work unless the PHP script handling the upload exists at `wp-content/uploads/` (which it does not). Placing it in that folder does not have the result you may expect. You might try placing it at `/wp-admin/` but this will change upload path for all wp-admin files. Unclear from your post where else users may be uploading files...

Comment: @tcox 
it may be that your server does not allow to set the "php.ini" using "htaccess", try this http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.htaccess` won't work unless the PHP script handling the upload exists at `wp-content/uploads/` (which it does not). Placing it in that folder does not have the result you may expect because it only impacts scripts located in that folder.

You might try placing `.htaccess` file into `/wp-admin/` which will change upload settings for all files handled inside the admin PHP scripts.

Unclear from your post where else users may be uploading files... are you using upload forms in your public-facing website? If so, you may not want to update the settings server-wide. If not, I see no big risks in making the change.

Comment: Your answer is "on", like I said can be a lock server, there is no way to be sure of his problem. I'll remove the -1 you, but please edit your question.

Comment: Re-read the OP's post. He says clearly that `.htaccess` file works when placed at root: "This does work if I put this in the websites .htaccess file though."  You are misinterpreting. The `.HTACCESS` directives are working, he just doesn't know where to place it to isolate to the admin upload (instead of globally across entire website).

Comment: I do not know where you read it, but oh well I had already removed the -1, 
even so it is likely that parameters like `php_*` does not work. +1 referring to another stretch of your answer that talks about `/wp-admin/`

Comment: I ended up putting the .htaccess into wp-admin like you suggested so that the public can't abuse the limits.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For increase PHP's file upload limit.

> > In php.ini file, change the parameter to whatever size you need 
> >     (example: )

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
```

...
Simply create blank text file. Save As php.ini

**Inside the text file copy-paste the following:**

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

============================

Unable to access root directory , than 
add this to top of wp-config.php
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');

Answer (score 0):

To Increase the Maximum file size upload in wordpress

find the php.ini location

```
#find / -iname php.ini
```

Get into the folder **By default it is 2M** we can incerase by setting value to the parameter

```
#vim php.ini
 upload_max_filesize = <Userdefined size>   (For eg 20M)
 post_max_size = <Userdefined size >
```

Then if you are using **php7.0** restart **php7.0-fpm service**

```
#systemctl reload php7.0-fpm.service
```

Answer (score 0):

If .htaccess not change value and also php.ini not change values, search for .user.ini file in root folder server and search for upload_max_filesize and post_max_size values and replace them.

Answer (score 0):

For increasing PHP's file upload limit.

Go to wordpress root directory and open .htaccess file. In my case it was found in /var/www/html

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

The above code increased my file upload limit to 128 MB in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

**2021:**

1. Access `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini`
2. Increase the value of `post_max_size`. The default value is `8M`.
3. Restart the server with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score -3):

Try to add this to `functions.php` of your theme

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '10M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '20M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '32M' );
```