# trying to add more mb in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

i try to change my .htaccess file from FTP but everytime i try to add this

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

then it will give a 500 server error

i tried it in various ways

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
# END WordPress
```

or

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
# BEGIN WordPress


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are you trying on a live server or on a local server? 
add code in functions.php file.
`@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );`

Comment: See the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633553/increasing-the-upload-size-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the php properties must reside inside the `php.ini` file and not inside the apache `.htaccess`.

Here https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php you can find all the settings and the instructions.